# QNX - finding an equivalent to command line 'tree'

Tags: tree, command, qnx

Tried to find an equivalent to Linux command line 'tree' on QNX.
I found some bash scripts for Linux but fails to run on QNX.
If anyone would know how to ? ... or as a script already running on QNX.

```
This works -
#!/bin/bash
pwd=$(pwd)
echo Tree of: $pwd
find $pwd -print | sed -e 's;$pwd;\.;g;s;[^/]*\/;|__;g;s;__|; |;g'
#very simple script. REALLY!
echo ‘|__end tree’
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Simulate cmd tree on QNX

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  path="."
  level=999
else
  path=$1
  level=${2:-999}
fi

if [ ! -d $path ]; then
  echo "$path is not a directory"
  exit 1
fi

BLUE="\033[1;34m"
WHITE="\033[0m"
dircount=0
filecount=0

display_tree() {
  local prefix=""
  local i=0
  while [ $i -lt $1 ]; do
    prefix="$prefix  "
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  done

  for file in $(ls $2); do
    filepath=$2/$file
    if [ -d $filepath ]; then
      echo "${prefix}├── ${BLUE}$file${WHITE}"
      dircount=$(( dircount + 1 ))

      if [ $1 -lt $level ]; then
        display_tree $(( $1 + 1 )) $filepath
      fi
    else
      echo "${prefix}├── $file"
      filecount=$(( filecount + 1 ))
    fi
  done
}

echo ${BLUE}$path${WHITE}
display_tree 0 $path
echo ""
echo "$dircount directories, $filecount files"
```